# Proof that two circles that intersect at only one point have the point of contact on the line of centers

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

There are many proofs that begin with constructing a common tangent at the point of contact. However, None of them makes sure that such a common tangent exists. What I want to state is that for two circles $\lambda(O_1;R_1)$ and $\Lambda(O_2;R_2)$ tangential at $A$,first we need a method that ensures that a common tangent exists at the point $A$ or we need to find an alternate proof of the above-mentioned statement. Can anyone show me how to prove the existence of the common tangent?

Also,I tried proving the above theorem alternatively(Please let me know if there are any mistakes). Note: I am using the same notation as the previous paragraph.

Suppose I assume that $A$ doesn't lie on the line of centers. If so, construct $A^{'}O_1$ such that $\angle A^{'}O_1O_2=\angle AO_1O_2$ and $O_1A=O_1A^{'}$ on the side opposite to $A$. It is easy to see that $\Delta AO_1O_2=\Delta A^{'}O_1O_2$ or that $A'$ too lies on both the circles. This violates the fact that the two circles are tangential. Hence, proved.

Comment: Looks good to me. You've proven that, if two circles have a *single* common point $A$, it must be on the line $O_1O_2$ connecting their centres. Now the common tangent exists as the normal to $O_1O_2$ at the point $A$. I see no problem with this proof, and it uses congruence beautifully.

Comment: I guess you mean circles in the Euclidean plane. Which kind of proof do you expect? Based on analytic geometry or on the Euclidean geometry (axiomatic approach)? You should include these informations in your question.